# VBA composition for java-like inheritance

Tags: vba, oop, inheritance, catia

Expanding a bit on this question [VBA inheritance pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375031/vba-inheritance-pattern)

I'm reproducing a basic inheritance pattern in VBA,
but I would like to understand If there is a more efficient and terse way to accomplish that.

Consider this little test-case.

IAnimal.cls

```
'declaration
Public Sub eat()
End Sub

Public Sub breathe()
End Sub
```

Animal.cls : the superclass

```
Implements IAnimal

' method implementation
Private Sub IAnimal_eat()
    Debug.Print "I'm eating something..."
End Sub

Private Sub IAnimal_breathe()
    Debug.Print "I'm brething..."
End Sub
```

Cat.cls : a subclass of Animal

```
Private super As IAnimal

Implements IAnimal

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set super = New Animal
End Sub


'#------------------------------------------------
' methods called when object is accessed as an IAnimal implementor. 
' I HAVE TO re-implement all of them also here in the subclass (in java I don't need to. It's sufficient to implement them in the superclass)
Private Sub IAnimal_eat()
    Me.eat
End Sub

Private Sub IAnimal_breathe()
    Me.breathe
End Sub


'#--------------------------------------------------
' subclass-only methods
' To access those methods I MUST DECLARE the object as Cat (Dim tom as Cat)
Public Sub meow()
Debug.Print "meow..."
End Sub


'#------------------------------------------------ 
' superclass methods
' Since I need to declare the cat object as a Cat (see above)
' I'm FORCED TO explicitly re-implement all of the superclass methods,
' even those that I don't need to override
' otherwise I can't access them

'@Override
Public Sub eat()
    Debug.print "I'm  eating a fish!"
End Sub

'I'm forced to re-implement also this method, in order to use it directly on a *Cat* object
'@Unnecessary-Override
Public Sub breathe()
    super.breathe 
End Sub
```

Test.bas

```
Sub Main()

    Dim snowball As IAnimal
    Set snowball = New Cat

    Dim tom As Cat
    Set tom = New Cat

    snowball.meow  'ERROR Method or data member not found <---- cannot access the Cat-only method "meow"
    tom.meow  '<--- prints "meow"

    ' creates a Dog, another subclass of Animal
    Dim pluto As Dog
    Set pluto = New Dog

    'create a collection for all my animals
    Dim myPets As Collection
    Set myPets = New Collection

    myPets.Add tom
    myPets.Add pluto

    Call feed(myPets) '<---- prints
                            'I 'm eating a fish
                            'meow...
                            'I 'm eating a bone
                            'woof...

End Sub

' a routine for showing how to manage an heterogeneous collection of animals
Sub feed(animals As Collection)

    For Each a In animals

        a.eat

        If TypeOf a Is Cat Then
            a.meow
        End If

        If TypeOf a Is Dog Then
            a.woof
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

By doing this, I can:

- call the `eat()` method on the Cat and Dog objects and **have the specific Overridden behavior**
- call the **subclass-only methods** (like `meow()`)
- pass an **heterogeneous collection of Animals** to a `feed` subroutine, that can "safely" call the Animal superclass methods and also trigger specific code based on the Animal subclass

This seems to work but it's cumbersome: imagine you need to implement many Animal subclasses (Dog, Bird, Armadillo, Platypus, Demogorgon,...).
The pattern above FORCES YOU TO:

1. re-implement all the methods of the IAnimal interface on ALL THE SUBCLASSES
2. re-implement (again) all the methods, to expose them from the subclass, even when override is not necessary. This is required expecially if you want to access ALSO the subclass-only methods.

So the question is: is there a more efficient/concise way to implement this example (and limit code rewriting for every subclass) ?

Comment: You can't implement an interface without implementing its members, there's no way around that. Point 2 raises a flag though: if a subclass can't be treated by the calling code exactly as any other subclass, then you're breaking the Liskov Substitution Principle - there should't be a need to re-implement all the methods again and expose them from the subclass.

Comment: In short, you should implement every member of interface. You can read more about this [here](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UCk0TqD7b3jORsDl3x).

Comment: thanks @MathieuGuindon for pointing out the Liskov Substitution Principle. I Tried to fix the code accordingly

Answer (score 5):

`tom` shouldn't be declared `As Cat` in the first place; the `feed` procedure is superfluous:

```
Sub Main()    
    Dim tom As IAnimal
    Set tom = New Cat    
    tom.eat    
End Sub
```

Now, in the `Cat` class, these members shouldn't need to exist:

```
'Superclass methods --- I have to explicitly override all methods :(
Public Sub eat()
    super.eat 
    Debug.print "...a fish!"
End Sub
```

In SOLID/OOP, you code against the interface, not the concrete type - that's why `tom` is an `IAnimal` and not a `Cat`. Being accessed through its `IAnimal` interface, `Cat.eat` is entirely redundant, and suggests that a `Cat` does something an `IAnimal` doesn't do, which violates SOLID principles: suddenly it becomes relevant that an `IAnimal` is a `Cat`, and it shouldn't be, because polymorphism allows `IAnimal` to be anything, and the *Liskov Substitution Principle* (LSP - the "L" of "SOLID") says any code that works with an `IAnimal` should be able to work identically regardless of what implementation of that interface it's given.

Abiding by these principles means that no `IAnimal` implementation should have a copy of `IAnimal` members on its default interface (e.g. `Cat.eat`, vs `IAnimal.eat`), and that entirely removes your point #2:

> 2. re-implements (again) all the methods, to expose them from the subclass, even when override is not necessary.

As for point 1...

> 1. re-implement all the methods of the IAnimal interface

That's a compiler requirement, and isn't a VBA quirk: be it in Java, C#, or VBA, you can't say "I'm implementing an interface" ...without implementing its members. Of course Java & C# allow for class inheritance, so your base class could say "I'm implementing an interface", implement all the members, and the derived classes would happily inherit them - but then, that's *inheritance*, not *composition* anymore.