# How to achieve flexible Object Composition?

Tags: vba, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

### Motivation behind the question

I've been learning how to do [Object Composition](https://medium.com/code-monkey/object-composition-in-javascript-2f9b9077b5e6) in Javascript using **Concatenative Inheritance** and wondered how I could accomplish something **similar** in VBA (which doesn't have inheritance).

**Object Composition**: I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish a "has a" relationship vs. a "is a" relationship. I want to be able to write simple **behavior** classes where they can be used by combining them together to make more complex classes.

I've created a simple example to demonstrate what I'd like to accomplish.

---

### Example use case

#### Testing Module

Here are some examples of what might be used. For this question though, I'll just focus on the example use of the `Fighter` class.

The `Fight` method is actually calling the `Fight` method in the `CanFight` class. It debugs a message and reduces stamina by 1.

```vb
'MOST EXCITING GAME OF ALL TIME! =)
Private Sub StartGame()

    Dim Slasher As Fighter
    Set Slasher = New Fighter
    Slasher.Name = "Slasher"

    Slasher.Fight '-> Slasher slashes at the foe!
    Debug.Print Slasher.Stamina '-> 99

    'MAGES CAN ONLY CAST (ONLY HAS MANA)
    Dim Scorcher As Mage
    Set Scorcher = New Mage
    Scorcher.Name = "Scorcher"
    Scorcher.Cast "fireball" '->Scorcher casts fireball!
    Debug.Print Scorcher.Mana '-> 99

    'CAN BOTH FIGHT & CAST (HAS BOTH STAMINA & MANA)
    Dim Roland As Paladin
    Set Roland = New Paladin
    Roland.Name = "Roland"
    Roland.Fight '-> Roland slashes at the foe!
    Roland.Cast "Holy Light" '-> Roland casts Holy Light!

End Sub
```

---

#### Fighter Class

This class has two public properties `Name` and `Stamina`.

This class also contains `FightAbility` which is an instance of the `CanFight` class. This is my attempt at trying to accomplish composition.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private FightAbility As CanFight
Private pName As String
Private pStamina As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    pStamina = 100
    Set FightAbility = New CanFight
End Sub

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Stamina() As String
    Stamina = pStamina
End Property

Public Property Let Stamina(ByVal Value As String)
    pStamina = Value
End Property

'This is the function that uses the ability to fight.
'It passes a reference to itself to the `CanFight` class
'giving it access to its public properties.
'This is my attempt at composition.
Public Sub Fight()
    FightAbility.Fight Me
End Sub
```

---

#### CanFight Class

This is the class that can be reused for other characters. *An Example is a `Paladin` class might need to also have the ability to fight*.

**The obvious issue with how this is laid out is that `state` is an `Object`**. The user won't know it needs to have `Stamina` and a `Name` property unless they look at the code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub Fight(ByRef State As Object)
    Debug.Print State.Name & " slashes at the foe!"
    State.Stamina = State.Stamina - 1
End Sub
```

---

### Summarizing the question

My example feels broken since there is no structure in place as far as what properties are needed in order to use it.

At the same time, I want to make sure my game characters can be flexible in having their own distinct properties. [Examples](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Composition-game) from above:

- `Fighter` uses: `canFight` (stamina)
- `Mage` uses: `canCast` (mana)
- `Paladin` uses both: `canFight` (stamina) and `canCast` (Mana)

If I created an `ICharacter` interface class then I feel like it would be locked into having all the properties for all types of Characters.

My question is how do I achieve structured but flexible **Composition** like this in VBA?

Comment: Try this https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/09/vba-inheritance-or-as-close-as-you-will.html

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53873314/1188513

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I read that post before asking this question. Maybe the thing I'm confused about is if I were to have an `ICharacter` class, wouldn't I then have to have all the properties listed in that class? Then my `Fighter` would also have `Mana` and everything else I can think about ahead of time? Correct me if I am way off! I really struggle for some reason in understanding interfaces.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon =) would `ICharacter` then contain only the base properties that I can think of for all possible Characters (`Name`, `Stamina`, `Health`)? And any unique property is in the specific classes? If this is the case, then what if I had a `CanCast` class that drains `Mana`. This wouldn't be able to work on the `ICharacter` since it doesn't contain `Mana`.

Comment: I have things to do right now, but I'll definitely get back to you (if not with an answer here, I'll comment with a link to a new blog article) - but yes, I'd have `ICharacter` with all the basic character properties.

Comment: I just added an example with additional classes to [Github](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Composition-game) in case that helps to have a better picture.

Comment: But ... you can do a kind of polymorphism in VBA: https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-interfaces-in-vba-how-and-why/ also please explain what you mean by "object composition", it would be better to explain your need that just using a link.

Comment: @pdem I added more clarity by what I mean object composition. I also added a note on why I might be nervous to use an interface as in it feels like it would lock my characters into having to share all the same properties including ones I wouldn't want them to have.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon just seeing if a blog article or answer is still something on the table sometime in the future? No pressure, just not getting a better understanding that I was hoping to gain from this question.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder - I had started working on this, got sidetracked, and it just vanished... Going with an answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very hard question to usefully answer IMO, mostly because the model is vastly oversimplified.

> ```
> Public Sub Fight(ByRef State As Object)
>     Debug.Print State.Name & " slashes at the foe!"
>     State.Stamina = State.Stamina - 1
> End Sub
> ```

If I made a *Barbarian Warrior* that fought with a massive warhammer, "slashes at the foe!" would sound like some funny understatement. Who/what is *the foe*? I know this is all theoretical & simplified (right?), but if we're talking about a game, then *the foe* needs to actually die at one point, doesn't it?

If we look at how a traditional JRPG might go about this, a `Fight` method would need to know the state of both the fighter and its target (let's keep the target singular for now), so for a start, it might go like this:

```
Public Sub Fight(ByVal fighterState As Object, ByVal targetState As Object)
    '...
End Sub
```

Basically the role of a `Fight` method would be to assess/implement the changes that need to happen on `targetState` based on a number of factors involving both `fighterState` and `targetState`. As such, a better name for it might be `Attack`, and we can assume that the `fighterState` contains information about what piece of weaponry is currently equipped and whether that weapon "slashes", "pierces", "crushes", or simply "hits" the target. Similarly, the `targetState` can be assumed to contain information about what pieces of armor are equipped on the target, and whether and how this equipment is able to deflect/nullify or reduce the amount of damage received. With such mechanics, we can even have a `PoisonBlade` slashing the target to deal what was calculated a 76 HP damage, plus a recurring 8 HP poison damage every turn unless the target consumes (or is otherwise given) an `Antidote` item to cure their poison state.

Now, whether the fighter is a `Fighter` or a `Paladin`, or a `BlackMage`, makes no difference: what the game mechanics needs isn't different properties and members in each character class. In fact, game mechanics couldn't care less what the character classes are, mechanics are the same for everyone regardless: `Fight` is a UI command, an ability like any other. The character is a `BlackMage` and has no weapon equipped? Fight off - and deal 1 HP damage, if any. The character is a `Paladin` and can decide to "fight" *or* "cast"? UI commands, not character class design.

How we design class modules is not quite like they do in textbooks with `Animal` and `Cat` and `Dog` where the `Dog` goes "woof" and the `Cat` goes "meow" and all the code did was invoke `Animal.Talk` in both cases and poof, glittering polymorphism-through-inheritance!

What I'm getting at is, real-world code doesn't do `Cat` and `Dog` classes, not any more than a real-world JRPG game would define different types for each possible character class in the game - an `Enum`, maybe, and different assets and resources, definitely; adding a new character class to your game should be adding *data*, not code. But the game mechanics don't need to be bothered with how different a `Paladdin` can be to a `BlackMage` or a `RedWizard`, because the different skills and abilities of a `Paladin` vs those of a `Fighter` or a `BlackBelt` *are* where *composition* should come into play.

See they're not different *methods*, they're different *objects*.

A `Fighter` doesn't have "no concept of mana", it's a `PlayableCharacter` instance that might be *composed* of a `CharacterStats` object where both the `MP` and the `MaxMP` properties begin the game at `0`.

So we take a step back and look at the big picture, and *without writing a single line of code*, we visualize how things need to coexist and what needs to be responsible for what, in order for the game to be able to make a `Paladin` slash at a `Dragon`: as we break down the required components and work out how they all relate to each others, we quickly realize that there's no need to *force* composition to happen anywhere, *it just happens*, out of necessity!

[image: some quick, incomplete and roughly approximate class diagram]

In a language that supported class inheritance, you might have `CharacterAbility` as the base/abstract class for things like `FightAbility`, `CastSpellAbility`, `UseItemAbility`, and other classes, each with wildly different implementations for their `Execute` method. In VBA you can't do that, so instead you might have an `ICharacterAbilityCommand` interface, and `FightAbility`, `CastSpellAbility`, `UseItemAbility` classes that implement it.

Now we can picture a `CombatController` class that knows everything about every actor: there's an instance of a `KillableGameCharacter` named `Red Dragon` that yields 380 XP and 1200 gold, has a `BiteAbility`, a `ClawAbility`, a `WingSpikeAbility`, and of course a `FireBreathAbility` - its `CharacterStats` are such that its `FireBreathAbility` will deal somewhere between 600 and 800 fire-elemental damage to our Paladin.

Ha! Noticed that? Just by uttering how things interact with each other, we know that `ICharacterAbilityCommand.Execute` needs to take the `CharacterStats` of the executing character in order to be able compute just how fierce that dragonfire is. That way we can later reuse the `FireBreathAbility` for a weaker `Wyvern` monster. And since we're taking in a `CharacterStats` object, whether they're the stats of a *Paladin*, the stats of a *Black Mage*, the stats of a *Red Dragon* or those of a *Slime*, makes no difference whatsoever.

And *that* sounds very much exactly like the problem you were trying to tackle in the first place - just slightly more abstracted, such that you don't write code that reads like a *Dragon Warrior* battle transcript ;-)

[image: Kain Attacks!]

By having the `CharacterEquipment` affect the character's `CharacterStats` on equip, and any stats-affecting transient skills baked into the stats as soon as they're acquired/equipped/activated, we remove the need for `ICharacterAbilityCommand.Execute` to need anything other than the `CharacterStats` of the valiant knight/player, and the `CharacterStats` of the dragon/monster.

Comment: _poof, glittering polymorphism-through-inheritance_   +

Comment: I can't stop laughing, the way you described the Red Dragon with all it's methods, I pictured a massive beast, not the dragon in the picture LOL

Answer (score 4):

@Robert, I actually like your code.  However, I'm not sure it qualifies as composition. Actually, I think you've discovered a 'mixin' pattern, sort of,  (or maybe even the visitor pattern) so congratulations on that.  Here is composition as I see it.

So with the default member trick, we ship a Base property that allows access to all the base's classes methods (but not private state, which is a good thing IMHO). But because writing `foo.Base.Bar` in code is ugly, we pull a trick to make the Base property the default member so that it can be replaced with just a pair of brackets.  Thus, the composition becomes less ugly to look at and no need for a subclass to replicate all the base class's methods.

```
'* Test Module
Private Sub StartGame2()

    Dim oPaladin As Paladin
    Set oPaladin = New Paladin
    oPaladin().Name = "Pal"

    oPaladin().Fight '-> Pal slashes at the foe!
    Debug.Print oPaladin().Stamina '-> 99
    Debug.Print oPaladin.Mana
End Sub
```

The Fighter class

```
Option Explicit

Private pName As String
Private pStamina As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    pStamina = 100
End Sub

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Stamina() As String
    Stamina = pStamina
End Property

Public Property Let Stamina(ByVal Value As String)
    pStamina = Value
End Property

'* This is the function that uses the ability to fight.
'* It passes a reference to itself to the `CanFight` class
'* giving it access to its public properties.
'* This is my attempt at composition.
' Public Sub Fight()
'     FightAbility.Fight Me
'End Sub

Public Sub Fight()
    Debug.Print Me.Name & " slashes at the foe!"
    Me.Stamina = Me.Stamina - 1
End Sub
```

The Paladin.cls class as exported to disk and amended to pull the default member trick.

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Paladin"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private moBase As Fighter

'* To do the default member trick
'* 1) Export this module to disk;
'* 2) load into text editor;
'* 3) uncomment line with text Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0 ;
'* 4) save the file back to disk
'* 5) remove or rename original file from VBA project to make room
'* 6) Re-import saved file

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set moBase = New Fighter
End Sub

Public Function Base() As Fighter
    Attribute Item.VB_UserMemId = 0
    Set Base = moBase
End Function


Public Function Mana() As String
    Mana = "I don't know what Mana even means"
End Function
```

Comment: Wouldn't exposing `Fighter` as the base class in `Paladin` then expose everything of the `Fighter`? It seems like that is tightly coupling them together. This would make `Paladin` everything a fighter is and more! In reality, `Fighter` probably has its own advantages such as more attacks and different properties and methods. Really all that I would want to expose is the `Fight` method in this example.

Comment: ok, I am beginning to get a better handle on what you want.  Perhaps this is why you have tagged the question Dependency Injection.  I've visited this recently on my blog https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2019/05/vba-dependency-injection.html

Comment: @SMeaden I so glad I found your blog. Love it!